# How does the client acquire the IDL?

Tags: java, corba

An IDL is complied at the server to generate the Skeleton Code. 
The same IDL is used by the Client to generate the Stub code.
How does the client acquire the IDL to create the stub code ?
Is it that the IDL should be copied manually to all the clients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmer that has to implement the client should receive the IDL from the server programmer. He compiles this IDL to his stubs and in most cases the IDL is not put on the client system itself, just the application that contains the generated stub. Some scripting implementations like [R2CORBA](http://www.remedy.nl/en/r2corba) do also use the IDL at runtime, so check your CORBA implementation whether the IDL is only used to generate code or also used at runtime.